# one-pass force-directed graph drawing algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for a one-pass algorithm (or ideas of how to write it myself) that can calculate the two or three dimensional coordinates for a directed, unweighted graph. 
The only metadata the vertices have are title and category.

I need to implement this algorithm in a way that vertices can be added/removed without recalculating the entire graph structure.

This algorithm has to be applied to a large (5gb) dataset which is constantly changing.

My Google skills have led me to n-pass algorithms which are not what what I am looking for.

Comment: I am a bit confused - are you talking about layout algorithms such as these? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing

Comment: Well, calculating some coordinates (which should not repeat) is not that difficult. What are you looking for, a visualisation of clustered nodes? How should title and category be considered by the algorithm?

Comment: Actually I do. But I was not able to find a one-pass variant of a Force-directed graph drawing algorithm.

Comment: I think what you're describing is an oxymoron.  Force-directed algorithms simulate a physical system that represents the graph as masses subject to forces over time. Because computers can only operate on discrete values, time must be split into steps as in numerical integration. The resulting algorithms are inherently iterative. For big, dynamically changing graphs there are "local update" variants.  These limit the parts of the graph touched by iteration to improve performance, but they still require iteration.

Comment: How is the graph stored (adjacency list, matrix, ...)? How do 'change' events look like?

Comment: THe graph is stored in a simple mysql table with columns for a vertex and a column for the ids of the vertices its pointing to. Change events are handled with mysql triggers.

Comment: I agree with @Gene, force-directed algorithms are inherently iterative.

Comment: How fast is the data changing?  Would it be feasible to take a long time to come up with an initial layout, and then apply the updates as the new data comes in?

Comment: The data change frequency is about 1 update per second

Answer (score 2):

I guess your question might still be an open issue. I know a research project called Tulip (http://tulip.labri.fr/TulipDrupal/) which is a (large-scale) graph viewer. A paper on the method is available at http://dept-info.labri.fr/~auber/documents/publi/auberChapterTulipGDSBook.pdf and surely you can find more algorithms browsing the personal web page of D. Auber and his colleagues.

Answer (score 0):

There is a related question here:

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11889/an-algorithm-to-efficiently-draw-a-extremely-large-graph-in-real-time

The top answer has a number of papers that might be of interest. I think one of the keys to the problem is to try and recompute the location of a reduced amount of nodes in your graph.